# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for + HABM returns an array with empty string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, has-and-belongs-to-many

See my problem:

```
class MedicalRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :evaluations, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :evaluations, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
end

class Evaluation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :medical_record

  has_and_belongs_to_many :edemas

  validates :description, presence: true
end
```

My form shows the select fields with multiple attribute.

```
<%= form_for @medical_record do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :evaluations do |e| %>
    <%= e.text_field :description %>

    <%= e.collection_select :edema_ids, Edema.all.order(:title), :id, :title,
      { }, multiple: true %>
  <% end %>      
<% end %>
```

When I don't select any 'edema', the form sends an array with one empty string. So, the `reject_if` returns `false` and I need fill the description field. The `reject_if` should return `true` in this case.

What can I do for this to work as well?

Thanks very much

Comment: Can you include the HTML that's *currently* (in the "broken" state) being rendered for the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is simply to not have the empty string in your `:edema_ids` array, you can pass `include_hidden: false` to the `collection_select`.

That said, this will cause problems if you eventually want to "deselect" all edemas for an existing evaluation, because the browser will not send the `:edema_ids` array at all if its value is truly empty (since it's a multiple select), for roughly the same reason it wouldn't send an un-checked checkbox value.  Including the empty string in an otherwise empty array is the form helper's way of dealing with this browser behavior.

I *believe* it's advisable to allow the HTML form to submit the empty string array element (so the browser and Rails can each behave as expected in this situation), AND to use ActiveRecord's `reject_if: :all_blank` on the `:evaluations` association (assuming that truly is the behavior you're looking for).

You could achieve this without running into array-with-empty-string hangups by stripping out empty string elements from `:edema_ids` at some point after it's passed into the controller, but before it's evaluated by `:all_blank`.

Something akin to:

```
# Inside MedicalRecordsController

def create
  @medical_record = MedicalRecord.create(medical_record_params)
end

def update
  @medical_record = MedicalRecord.find(params[:id])
  @medical_record.update_attributes(medical_record_params)
end

private

  def medical_record_params
    # I assume you're using strong params to control what can be passed
    # through the controller.  If so, manipulate the params *after*     
    # calling .require() and .permit() on the params hash
    remove_empty_string_from_edema_ids(params)
  end

  def remove_empty_string_from_edema_ids(params_hash) # Use a better name than this
    params_hash[:evaluations].each do |evaluation|
      # Don't forget to use guard clause to prevent calling a
      # method on nil if :edema_ids is not present in evaluation
      evaluation[:edema_ids].reject!(&:empty) if evaluation[:edema_ids]
    end
  end
```

This (or something similar, as there are many ways to achieve the same result) would — in addition to correctly causing `:all_blank` to return `true` if the `:evaluation` truly is all blank — result in passing a truly empty array to the evaluation's `edema_ids=()` method; which would, thanks to some ActiveRecord association magic, result in the removal of all `:edemas` from that `Evaluation` instance.

Comment: These are the broad strokes.  Looking at the controller code again, though, I'm using `medical_record_params` incorrectly.  Will update in a bit...

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to write a custom `reject_if` method. If you provide a symbol, ActiveRecord looks for a method in the current class with that name and passes the submitted attributes hash for the `evaluation`.

```
class MedicalRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :evaluations, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :essentially_blank

  def essentially_blank(attributes)
    attributes[:description].blank? && attributes[:edema_ids][0].blank?
  end
end
```

Note that while `[""].blank?` is false `"".blank?` is true, which is why I'm getting the first object of the array and checking its `blank`-ness.

You can look at [the Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to see more examples for how to accomplish custom behavior on `reject_if`.

Comment: I thought can be exist a way to send a empty array instead of an array with an empty string. Ok for write a custom reject_if, It should works. I was avoiding this way because there are 5+ HABM for evaluation :( Thanks Lanny

Comment: I'd lean toward fixing the existence of the empty string (could pass `include_hidden: false` to your `collection_select`), instead of writing a custom method to check blankness.  
But if you do go the custom method route, be sure it's flexible enough to accommodate the eventual addition of new attributes on `Evaluation`.  If, down the road, you want to add a `:title` attribute to `Evaluation`, and sent over an evaluation with a valid `:title` string but blank `:description` and an `:edema_ids` array with an empty string, this `essentially_blank()` method would still evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @jasonmklug , I didn't know about `include_hidden: false`. Just read up on it and that makes sense too. How would you avoid the converse scenario (a user explicitly wants to remove all children from the association)?

Comment: And @ThiagoGuimarães, here's a link to the collection_select documentation on `include_hidden`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html